# NullReferenceException when setting AutoSizeMode to AllCells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I am manually binding an entity framework code first table to a datagridview. When I set the AutoSizeMode to AllCells and add an instance to the table I get a NullReferenceException during Add.

The code runs like this:

```
dbContext.Persons.Load();
myDataGridView.DataSource = dbContext.Persons.Local.ToBindingList();

myDataGridView.Columns[ "Description" ].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

Person p = new Person();
p.Name = "Tester Alfred";
p.Description = "Description"; //no more properties, only those two (Id Property is annotated as [Key]

dbContext.Persons.Add( p ); // this throws a NullReferenceException
```

Here is the relevant part from the stack trace:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddSingleObject(EntitySet entitySet, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, String argumentName)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassd.<Add>b__c()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   bei System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
```

The table Persons is otherwise empty. When I remove the AutoSize - Instruction everything is fine.

Plattform: WInForms in .Net 4.5.1 using Studio 2013; Running Win8 Pro, EF 6.1.3

Edit: Removed typo that introduced a second gridview

Comment: I am pleased to find this is not a duplicate of the usual.

Comment: What happens if you move the add of the new person to before the data binding?

Comment: myDataGridView.Columns[ "Description" ] are you sure that this column exists??

Comment: @John: Thanks - than all is well... (I can not figure out how those are related..)

Comment: @Jacek: Yes - it is created by binding the DataSource (Description is a public property of Person)

Comment: I cannot obtain the same error on my machine. I am pretty sure the cause of the problem does not lies in the presented code but it is hidden somewhere else. In your method do you do something else with dbContext? How do you instantiate it? In using or do you keep it somewhere for some longer time?

Comment: Thanks mr100 - I will check. The context is created outside of the function within the same thread and is not destroyed.

Comment: Is there reason to have 2 different grids? myDataGrid and myDataGridView?

Comment: @Szer: Sorry - this is a typo in the post here!

Comment: It is generally considered a bad practice to keep DbContext alive for a long time. Instead it should be instantiated when needed and disposed immediately after that.

Comment: What other columns are being displayed in the grid?  My assumption would be that if auto-size is the trigger for the exception, then auto-size is referencing something that it expects to have a value...and doesn't.  This to me would say "there is a column that contains a null which is not expected to be null".

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon I can't reproduce this either... What happens if you try to do some other operation on the column, like setting the headertext, or visible, or something? Or set autosize on another column? You said *The code runs like this*, is that actually the code (copy and paste)? Or did you pare down from a larger file?

Comment: @Nevyn & Drew: Thanks for the feedback, I will try that later on

Comment: @Nevyn has a point there, does your Id column allow null? If yes, change the mode to DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells, and see what happens.

Comment: @Oakcoll: Yes, it is required but inserting (and editing) is disabled

Comment: Entity Framework would set the ID to the default of 0 for a `Key` field, and autosizing a column with a cell containing a null value should just default to sizing for the header I think. I'm with @mr100, I think the problem is somewhere else and this is just a weird symptom.

Comment: AutoSize all cells means the data grid view needs to evaluate the result for each column.  The EF needs to supply the result for each row.  It appears that you are probably binding to a foreign key column.  If the value in the row does not match up to a row in the foreign table, then the datagridview will throw this error.  The EF has a problem where the value in the table MUST match the value in the foreign table case-wise sensitive ... regardless of whether or not SQL is case-sensitive.  The EF is using the CLR to perform entity matching ... which is case-sensitive.

Comment: If the case-sensitive data is the issue, typically it is best just to ensure the foreign key values match the PK values in the database.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks, that was the issue! One property was not set to lazy loading thus populating null values. Mind to put your comment as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @Marc: Please put in your comment as answer so I can accept and u get the bounty!

Comment: Any chance of still getting this bounty?

Comment: Yep, I started a new bounty :-) You will get it in 24h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoSize all cells means the data grid view needs to evaluate the result for each column. The EF needs to supply the result for each row. It appears that you are probably binding to a foreign key column. If the value in the row does not match up to a row in the foreign table, then the datagridview will throw this error. The EF has a problem where the value in the table MUST match the value in the foreign table case-wise sensitive ... regardless of whether or not SQL is case-sensitive. The EF is using the CLR to perform entity matching ... which is case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the data first and then use it

```
myDataGridView .Columns[ "Description" ] .AutoSizeMode  = 
DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode .AllCells ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
 DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[Index];
 column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```